# When to use $firebaseObject in place of $firebaseArray

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using angularfire for my project and have experienced the following limitations of `$firebaseObject` :

1. `orderBy` and `filter` don't work on them
2. I couldn't directly manipulate them as objects in js file

Is there anything that `$firebaseArray` can't do but `$firebaseObject` can ?

Comment: You should use `$firebaseObject` when you have a single object and `$firebaseArray` when you have a list of object. Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say which case you're hitting.

Comment: Why should you blindly use firebaseObject instead of firebaseArray ? Is there a reason (performance, features...) that make it a viable choice over an Array ? If you query for an Array and only have one result, it will return an array with length of 1 and if none are there 0. On the other hand if you query for an object and find one, ok you get your object but if you find none you have to look oor $value === null which is less practical to use then length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation from firebase. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray

If you want to sort the objects treat them as array. See solution from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286#issuecomment-14303275).

```
app.filter('toArray', function() { return function(obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) return obj;
    return _.map(obj, function(val, key) {
        return Object.defineProperty(val, '$key', {__proto__: null, value: key});
    });
}});
```

Example markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in object | toArray | orderBy:'priority' | filter:fieldSearch">
  {{val.$key}} : {{val}} 
</div>
```